# Was the Aruch Hashulchan Sephardic?

Tags: rabbis, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, historical-figures, aruch-hashulchan

No, wait. Before you shake your head in disgust and think, "What are you thinking? Of course he's Ashkenaz!"consider what he writes in סימן מז סעיף יב:

> ברכה ראשונה היא: "אשר קדשנו במצותיו, וצונו על דברי תורה". כלומר: לדבר וללמוד בתורה. והאשכנזים גורסים "לעסוק בדברי תורה"

He writes the Sephardic/Kabbalistic minhag first!
Furthermore, I recently heard from a very learned and well known Rabbi that him being Ashkenaz is a misconception, and he was actually Sephardic.

Are there any sources to this?

P.S.- Yes, I know his last name is Epstein. And also, I know it's hard to believe, but I can't just disregard what this Rabbi said as completely incorrect.

Something that I think should be clarified: Look, I don't believe he's Sephardic either. I'm just asking whether somebody else has something revolutionary that I or you have never seen before that establishes him as Sephardic. If you don't think so, feel free to ignore this question then.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein

Comment: Yeah..... Wikipedia isn't always the best source. Maybe it was either written by someone else or maybe he was secretly Sephardic?

Comment: It's plausible to suggest he was influenced by his interaction with Chabad Chassidim, and perhaps was closeted about that (they also say על דברי תורה), but sefardi? No.

Comment: @Yishai He keeps mentioning Sepharadim throughout the book. Not Hasidim.

Comment: There was a community of sefardim in Russia, he just wasn't from them. I don't know how much was even left by then. I can inverse what you said: he mentions ashkenazim throughout the sefer. It shows he was comprehensive not sefardi. Anyway, most likely he was ashkenazi and not Chassidic.

Comment: But why would an Ashkenazi, who probably never had significant contact with Sepharadim, write about Sepharadim so extensively, as to provide their opinion first?

Comment: @147zcbm You are welcome to ask why in this case he wrote things a little funny. To establish that he must have been a closeted Sefardi bc of this quote is beyond absurd, to put it politely.

Comment: Look, I don't believe he's Sephardic either. I'm just asking whether somebody else has something revolutionary that I or you have never seen before that establishes him as Sephardic. If you don't think so, feel free to ignore this question then.

Comment: @147zcbm He sometimes mentions Ashkenazim first, too. If you want to understand his view on the matter, see what he writes in OC [68:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A1%D7%97#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A1.D7.97_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.92) and [89:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A4.D7.98_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96).

Comment: I actually heard from an Polish Sephardi that the Epsteins were Sephardi themselves. No clue, but it is certainly possible, considering that there were numerous Spanish expatriates who emigrated to Poland after 1492.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt See the two answers

Comment: @147zcbm Because the Rama (Ashkenaz) was written on the Shulchan Aruch (Sefardi), and people tend to say  the main opinion last (Basraah)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

147zcbm made what even 147zcbm thought was a wild inference from how things are ordered in the *Aruch Hashulchan*. You'll never believe what happened next.

---

The [*Aruch Hashulchan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aruch_HaShulchan) was written by [R' Yechiel Michel Halevi Epstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein). His son, [R' Baruch Halevi Epstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Epstein), author of the [*Torah Temima*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah_Temimah), also wrote an autobiographical work called *Mekor Baruch*. His research, presented there in [Section 1, pages 671-2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48313&st=&pgnum=9), indicates that the Levite [Epstein family](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F) originated as an offshoot of the prominent [Benveniste family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benveniste) of Spain. Apparently, when the Benvenistes were [expelled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alhambra_Decree) from Spain with the rest of the Jews in 1492, some of them landed in the Hessian German town of [Eppstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eppstein) and took its name as their surname.

So, based on this lineage, the Epsteins could consider themselves [*Sepharadim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sephardi_Jews), as their forebears quite literally came from Spain. However, it seems that in the ensuing centuries in Germany and Eastern Europe, they integrated into the [Ashkenazi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashkenazi_Jews) community. R' YM Epstein's primary mentor [was](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F) R' [Eliyahu Goldberg](http://www.jewishgen.org/yizkor/bobruisk/byb269.html), the [*Av Beit Din*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Av_Beit_Din) of his home town, Russian [Babruysk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babruysk), who most likely didn't transmit *Sepharadi* traditions to him. He served as the rabbi of the mainly-Chabad community in [Novozybkov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novozybkov) and then of the community in [Navahrudak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navahrudak), and neither community would probably have hired a rabbi who would transmit primarly *Sepharadi* traditions. That said, maybe he still had a certain affinity for his *Sepharadi* roots as a result of being aware of his lineage, which comes out in his writing.

Comment: +1 respect to the hard work got put in, agav his family already by the point of the Aruch Hashulchan was completely "assimilated" as Ashkenazim

Comment: I totally set out to find counter-evidence by finding documentation of where RYM"E's forebears and mentors came from, so I could write an authoritative "no." But Hebrew WP had other plans.

Comment: +1 IIRC the people of Eppstein were very nice to the family and it was out of Hakaras Hatov that they took on that name. But there is nothing AFAIK in any of his writings about minhagim and the like which indicate he kept anything Sefardic. The basis of this question forgets that the in Shulchan Aruch land, sefardi comes first, ashkenazi second. Ordering his words like this proves nothing about anything.

Comment: @user6591 IYRC from where?

Comment: @Isaac from the Mekor Baruch. I don't see that in the page you linked so either I saw it somewhere else in the book or I am mistaken.

Answer (score 7):

The Aruch Hashulchan was himself Ashkenazi. But he claimed that he descended from a prominent Sephardic Rabbinical family.

The Aruch Hashulchans son Rabbi Baruch Epstein [writes in his book Mekor Baruch](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48313&st=&pgnum=9) which details his life and family history, that his family had a tradition that they were originally expelled from Spain along with the majority of Spanish Jewry in 1492. He writes that his family as well as some Horowitzs are descendents of the great [Rabbinical Benveniste family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benveniste). His family eventually made its way to Lithuania and took on Ashkenazic minhagim, but this tradition [always held a prominent place](http://www.sefaria.org/Obadiah.1.20?lang=he-en) in the home of the Aruch Hashulchan.

H/t to IsaacMoses

Comment: Where did you get "this tradition always held a prominent place in the home of the Aruch Hashulchan" from? I didn't see anything about the AH"Sh's attitude to his *Sepharadi* roots in the immediate vicinity of his son's [discussion](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48313&st=&pgnum=9) of their Benveniste lineage. Is it later in the book?

Comment: I remember reading that either in a book from Aharon Rakkeffet "Rakkeffet Aharon" or in Mekor Baruch itself.

Comment: You could improve this answer by [edit]ing in your sources, even if vaguely cited.

Comment: What I mean by prominence I mean that it was a source of pride in his home.

Comment: Ah, yes. His son goes on at length about the significance of the fact that the family goes all the way back to the exile in Spain [mentioned in Tanach](http://www.sefaria.org/Obadiah.1.20?lang=he-en).

Comment: Please feel free to improve your answer however you want, including by incorporating sources or information from the other answer. Everything here is owned by the community and [licensed](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for copying and remixing, with attribution.

Comment: I know a family Epstein in my community who are definitely Ashkenaz

Comment: Not all Epsteins. Only the levite ones who spell their last name with an Ayin.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, I saw an earlier print of the Aruch HaShulchan and as I recall, it had his Spanish family name in brackets under his name.